# PHP, using xpath to get all svgs inside <li>

Tags: php, xpath

I have this html:

```
<ul class="details">

<li>
  <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#icon-location"></use></svg>
  
    <span>São João de Vêr, Aveiro</span>
  
</li>



<li>
  <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#icon-contract"></use></svg>
  Permanente
</li>


<li>
  <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#icon-duration"></use></svg>
  Horário completo
</li>
```

From here, I need to grab the content of each li with separate data (svg and text after).

I try this, but I only get content of li without sgv element:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);

    $div = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="details"]');
    $div = $div->item(0);
    $result = $dom->saveXML($div);
    dd($result);
```

Result:

```
<ul class="details">    
<li>     
    <span>São João de Vêr, Aveiro</span>      
</li>
<li>
  Permanente
</li>
<li>      
  Horário completo
</li>
```

Expected result:

```
<ul class="details">  
<li>
  <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#icon-location"></use></svg>    
    <span>São João de Vêr, Aveiro</span>      
</li>
<li>
  <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#icon-contract"></use></svg>
  Permanente
</li>
<li>
  <svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#icon-duration"></use></svg>
  Horário completo
</li>
```

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: What exactly is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks @JackFleeting for this tip :). I edited the post and add the expected result.

Comment: The code works for me: https://ideone.com/06wsMP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$div = $xpath->query('//ul[@class="details"]/*');
foreach($div as $d){
  $result = $dom->saveXML($d);
  echo($result);
  }
```